# Angular 5 - Refresh a component (Not the whole page)

Tags: typescript, refresh, typescript2.0, angular-components, angular5

Right now, I have a button called: Reset Defaults

I'm calling `(click)="onResetDefault()"` within the button tag and I want the `onResetDefault()` method to just refresh that specific component and NOT the entire window (unlike `location.reload()`. How would I do that? Answers using practices of angular 2+ would be appreciated :)

Comment: I used local storage service to negate this refresh

Comment: All you have to do is have the component invoke its OnChanges lifecycle hook. This will force the component to redraw.

Answer (score 0):

Create a local variable in your Component (Assuming using typescript if Angular 2+):

```
myValue: string;
```

Then you manipulate that variable through other ways.
And then you call your onResetDefault() method in your Component, which looks like:

```
onResetDefault(): void {
    myValue = 'Default';
}
```

I do not see how and why you would trigger a page reload, but this should do what you want up here.

in your template (.html) then surely it is somewhere presented, the simplest would be like:

```
my value is: {{ myValue }}
```